# Elastic Beanstalk: Application directory/script location on the EC2 Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a flask application on AWS. I need to access a python script inside the App directory at runtime (to run a daily cron job). 
I've SSH access to the EC2 server, but I can't locate the directory in which AWS has uploaded my code. Any idea where AWS puts the code?

Comment: are you using elastic beanstalk?

Comment: Yup, using elastic beanstalk.

Comment: I edited your question in order to clarify you are talking about elastic beanstalk ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Elastic beanstalk organizes python code under: `/opt/python/`

Specifically your current app is available under `/opt/python/current/app`
(`/opt/python/current` is a link to `/opt/python/bundle/${bundle_version}/`)

Remember that Beanstalk makes use of **virtualenv** and its location is: `/opt/python/run/venv`

If you want to use a python shell with all the environment variable you are expecting you have to:

```
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
```

then:

```
source /opt/python/current/env
```

(with the first command you activate the virtual environment with the seconds you load up all the environment variables you did define via eb settings)